# How to read stdin buffer in advance before an EOF in python3?

Tags: python, node.js, stdin

In my python code I wrote the following function to receive self-defined binary package from stdin.

```
def recvPkg():
     ## The first 4 bytes stands for the remaining package length
    Len = int.from_bytes(sys.stdin.buffer.read(4), byteorder='big', signed=True)
     ## Then read the remaining package
    data = json.loads(str(sys.stdin.buffer.read(Len), 'utf-8'))
     ## do something...

while True:
    recvPkg()
```

Then, in another Node.js program I spawn this python program as a child process, and send bytes to it.

```
childProcess = require('child_process').spawn('./python_code.py');
childProcess.stdin.write(someBinaryPackage)
```

I expect the child process to read from its stdin buffer once a package is received and give the output. But it doesn't work, and I think the reason is that the child process won't begin to read unless its stdin buffer receive a signal, like an EOF. As a proof, if I close childProcess's stdin after stdin.write, the python code will work and receive all the buffered packages at once. This is not the way I want because I need childProcess's stdin to be open. So is there any other way for node.js to send a signal to childProcess to inform of reading from stdin buffer?

(sorry for poor english.

Comment: Are you sure `Len` is correct? `sys.stdin.buffer.read(Len)` will read bytes from stdin until it has received `Len` bytes. Until that point, it will be a blocking call. So `.read(5)` won't do anything if you send it "abcd", but the moment you send the final "e" it will continue. If `Len` includes the bytes that determine the length of the message, you will need to change your data loading to `.read(Len-4)`.

Comment: @alxwrd Thanks for your comment. I'm sure that python sys.stdin.buffer.read() won't read anything until some flush event occur. It's true that .read(5) won't read when received only 'abcd', but this is not my situation. I send long bytes to childProcess and if I add "childProcess.stdin.end()" after write(), then python code read. Otherwise, it won't. I also try to redirect the input from a file, and it works, because stream from a file will have an EOF in the end, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia (*emphasis mine*):

> Input from a terminal **never really "ends" (unless the device is disconnected)**, but it is useful to enter more than one "file" into a terminal, so a **key sequence** is reserved to indicate end of input. In UNIX the translation of the keystroke to EOF is performed by the **terminal driver**, so a program does not need to distinguish terminals from other input files.

There is no way to send an `EOF` character how you are expecting. `EOF` isn't really a character that exists. When you're in a terminal, you can press the key sequence <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> on Windows, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> on UNIX-like enviroments. These produce control characters for the terminal (code 26 on Windows,  code 04 on UNIX) and are read by the terminal. The terminal (upon reading this code) will then essentially stop writing to a programs `stdin` and *close* it.

In Python, a file object will `.read()` forever. The EOF condition is that `.read()` returns `''`. In some other languages, this might be `-1`, or some other condition.

Consider:

```
>>> my_file = open("file.txt", "r")
>>> my_file.read()
'This is a test file'
>>> my_file.read()
''
```

The last character here isn't `EOF`, there's just nothing there. Python has `.read()` until the end of the file and can't `.read()` any more.

Because `stdin` in a special type of 'file' it doesn't have an end. *You* have to define that end. The terminal has defined that end as the control characters, but here you are not passing data to `stdin` via a terminal, you'll have to manage it yourself.

### Just closing the file

> Input [...] never really "ends" (unless the device is disconnected)

Closing `stdin` is probably the simplest solution here. `stdin` is an infinite file, so once you're done writing to it, just close it.

### Expect your own control character

Another option is to define your own control character. You can use whatever you want here. The example below uses a NULL byte.

Python

```
class FileWithEOF:
    def __init__(self, file_obj):
        self.file = file_obj
        self.value = bytes()
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def read(self):
        while True:
            val = self.file.buffer.read(1)
            if val == b"\x00":
                break
            self.value += val
        return self.value

data = FileWithEOF(sys.stdin).read()
```

Node

```
childProcess = require('child_process').spawn('./python_code.py');
childProcess.stdin.write("Some text I want to send.");
childProcess.stdin.write(Buffer.from([00]));
```

### You might be reading the wrong length

I think the value you're capturing in `Len` is less than the length of your file.

Python

```
import sys

while True:
    length = int(sys.stdin.read(2))
    with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(sys.stdin.read(length))
```

Node

```
childProcess = require('child_process').spawn('./test.py');

// Python reads the first 2 characters (`.read(2)`)
childProcess.stdin.write("10"); 

// Python reads 9 characters, but does nothing because it's
// expecting 10. `stdin` is still capable of producing bytes from
// Pythons point of view.
childProcess.stdin.write("123456789");

// Writing the final byte hits 10 characters, and the contents
// are written to `test.txt`.
childProcess.stdin.write("A");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested the FileWithEOF and it worked well.Thongh it didn't solve my problem, and I'm wondering if something went wrong in my NodeJs code, maybe something stuck in the callback mechanism. Anyway, for this question you have given enough resolutions and explanations. Thanks :)